# How can I import .csv file data into gsl_vectors in C++?

Tags: c++, csv, vector, gsl

I have a .csv file that looks like:

```
X,Y,Z
0,0,0
0,0,0
-0.00624347,-0.0182673,1.00063
-0.00845628,-0.0374925,1.00058
-0.00494793,-0.0295639,0.927447
-0.00285682,-0.0926582,0.885783
-0.00832563,-0.02957,0.697834
```

And I want to put it into three *gsl_vectors* (from GSL: https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/vectors.html) corresponding to the column X, column Y and column Z respectively. The reason why I want to do this is because I later want to use the functions that are implemented in the [GNU Scientific Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Scientific_Library) on this data. I want to emphasize that these functions can only work on gsl_vectors and not on std:vectors.

My approaches:

1. Put the data from the .csv into std:vectors, and then transform those vectors into gsl_vectors. That did not work.
2. Put the data from the .csv file into gsl_vectors directly:

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <fstream>
   #include <istream>
   #include <string>
   #include <sstream>
   #include <algorithm>
   #include <gsl/gsl_linalg.h>
   #include <gsl/gsl_vector.h>

   struct acceleration {
       gsl_vector AccX;
       gsl_vector AccY;
       gsl_vector AccZ;
   };

   // Function prototypes
   acceleration read_csv(acceleration& A);
   // End function prototypes

   int main(void)
   {
       // ==================READ THE CSV=========================
       acceleration data;
       data = read_csv(data);
       printf("/n");
       gsl_vector_fprintf(stdout, &data.AccX, "%lf");

       return 0;
   }

   acceleration read_csv(acceleration& SA)
   {
       std::string buffer; /* Declare a buffer for the data that will be read */
       std::string bacx, bacy, bacz;
       std::ifstream inputfile;
       inputfile.open("buffer.csv"); /* Open file for reading */
       if (!inputfile.is_open())
       {
           std::cout << "Error opening file" << std::endl;
       }

       std::stringstream aux(buffer);
       getline(aux, bacx, ',');
       getline(aux, bacy, ',');
       getline(aux, bacz, ',');
       size_t i{ 0 };

       while (getline(inputfile, buffer))
       {
           std::stringstream aux(buffer);

           getline(aux, bacx, ',');
           if (bacx.compare("AX") != 0)
               gsl_vector_set(&SA.AccX, i, stod(bacx));

           getline(aux, bacy, ',');
           if (bacy.compare("AY") != 0)
               gsl_vector_set(&SA.AccY, i, stod(bacy));

           getline(aux, bacz, ',');
           if (bacz.compare("AZ") != 0)
               gsl_vector_set(&SA.AccZ, i, stod(bacz));
           i++;
       }
       inputfile.close();
       return (SA);

   }
   ```

   This gives no output on the Console and if I debug it, the function `gsl_vector_set` throws an exception:

   > Exception thrown at 0x7A5EED1A (gsld.dll) in progr.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x3333332

   At `gsl_set_vector`'s line: `v->data[i * v->stride] = x;`
3. Put the .csv data into a gsl_block and then slice it into gsl_vectors. Here I get an exception when trying to put the data into the block. Then, for slicing the block into vectors, I assume I'll have to use the `gsl_vector_alloc_from_block()` function, yet I did not find any example on how to use this function. I do need to see how others use functions generally because I'm new to C++.
   Here is what I have until now for this idea:

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <fstream>
   #include <gsl/gsl_linalg.h>
   #include <gsl/gsl_vector.h>

   // Function prototypes
   gsl_block read_csv(void);
   // End function prototypes

   int main(void)
   {
       // ================== READ THE CSV INTO A BLOCK =========================
       gsl_block data;
       data = read_csv();
       // ================= NOW SLICE THE BLOCK: HOW? ==========================
       // Use gsl_vector_alloc_from_block(), but how?
       return 0;
   }

   // Function declarations
   gsl_block read_csv(void)
   {
       FILE* inputfile;
       fopen_s(&inputfile, "buffer.csv", "r"); /* Open file for reading */
       if (inputfile == NULL)
           std::cout << "file does not exist \n";
       fseek(inputfile, 0L, SEEK_END); // Go until the end
       int file_size = ftell(inputfile); // In order to tell the size of the file
       gsl_block* b = gsl_block_alloc(file_size);
       if(inputfile)
           gsl_block_fscanf(inputfile, b);

       fclose(inputfile);

       return *b;

   }
   // End function declarations
   ```

   If I run this I get:

   > Debug Error! abort() has been called

   And on the Console it is shown:

   > gsl: C:\DEV\vcpkg\buildtrees\gsl\src\gsl-2-fb511965d5.clean\block\fprintf_source.c:90: ERROR: fscanf failed
   > Default GSL error handler invoked.

   If I debug this, the `gsl_error` function throws an exception:

   > progr.exe has triggered a breakpoint.

   At `abort ();`

To sum up, I actually want to read the .csv file into gsl_vectors. If my approaches are not OK, it is understandable.

Comment: This question is answered on [sololearn](https://www.sololearn.com/Discuss/2848589/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-gsl_vectors-c).

Comment: Actually the suggestion on that did not work for me and I have given up on using the library

Comment: This is the subject of [a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415405/same-question-as-on-so-got-answered-on-another-website).

Comment: @lalal I have just posted my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68603409/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-gsl-vectors-c/70786091#70786091) below. Although you have given up on using the library, I would still suggest you try and lemme know if this solved the issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the CSV file into gsl vectors the following way:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <gsl/gsl_vector.h>

int main ()
{
  int i = 0, rows = 7;

  // Allocate vectors
  gsl_vector *X = gsl_vector_alloc (rows);
  gsl_vector *Y = gsl_vector_alloc (rows);
  gsl_vector *Z = gsl_vector_alloc (rows);

  // Open the file
  std::ifstream openfile("data.csv");
  openfile.ignore(10000, '\n'); // Ignore the header
  std::string line;

  while (getline(openfile, line, '\n'))
  {
    std::string a, b, c;
    std::stringstream iss(line);
    getline(getline(getline (iss, a, ','), b, ','), c, ',');
    // std::cout << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << std::endl;

    // Set vectors
    gsl_vector_set (X, i, std::stod(a));
    gsl_vector_set (Y, i, std::stod(b));
    gsl_vector_set (Z, i, std::stod(c));

    i += 1;
  }

  // Close the file
  openfile.close();

  for(i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
  {
      // Get vectors
      std::cout << gsl_vector_get (X, i) << "\t";
      std::cout << gsl_vector_get (Y, i) << "\t";
      std::cout << gsl_vector_get (Z, i) << "\n";
  }

  // Do some processing with the vectors

  // Free allocated memory at the end
  gsl_vector_free (X);
  gsl_vector_free (Y);
  gsl_vector_free (Z);

  return 0;
}
```

Firstly, I open the `data.csv` using `ifstream` and read each line into three variables (splitting them through a comma). Secondly, I cast them into `double` and store them in the gsl vectors. Lastly, I print them for verification.